# Is this a non-linear differential equation? And is there a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following two equations, and I'm not sure I'm analyzing them properly.
$$
I(t)=CV'(t)\\
V(t)I(t) = P + R_{C}I^{2}(t)\\
\text{Substitute:}\\
CV(t)V'(t) = P + R_{C}C^{2}(V'(t))^{2}\\
$$

If I'm right, this gives me a non-linear differential equation, which puts me well past my mathematical comfort zone.

Is this, in fact, a non-linear differential equation? If not, can anyone help alleviate my misunderstanding?
If it IS non-linear, does anyone recognize this as an equation that has been/can be solved? Or am I out of luck as far as an exact solution goes?

Comment: Apply the quadratic formula to get $V'(t) = \big(V(t)\pm\sqrt{V(t)^2-4PR_C}\big)\big/(2R_CC)$. It's still nonlinear and ugly, but now it's an ordinary differential equation.

Comment: @RahulNarain I'm not entirely sure you can just do that.

Comment: @Ed, I don't see why not. At any given $t$, $V(t)$ and $V'(t)$ are just real numbers, say $v$ and $w$ respectively. For $Cvw=P+R_CC^2w^2$ to hold, $w$ must be given by the quadratic formula. What else could it be?

Comment: Because there exists a constraint that $V(t)^2 > 4PR_C$ for $P, R_C > 0$ that does not exist in the differential algebraic form.

Comment: $I(t)$ is just a scaled version of $V'(t)$. If $V(\tau) < 4 PR_C$ for some $t = \tau$, then $I(t)$ would take a complex value. However, in the numerical solution, there are clearly values where $V(t) < 4PR_C$ and yet $I(t)$ is real-valued. That means that either the solution is wrong (which is possible), or that there is something else going on. However, the problem as originally formulated is a well-posed Index 1 DAE; `ode15s` should have no difficulty solving it.

Comment: @Ed, please use "@Rahul" when replying to my comments. The constraint is implicit in the DAE, as there is no real solution of the system when $V(t)^2 < 4PR_C$.

Comment: @RahulNarain My answer got bloated, so I deleted it. When I got in this morning, I re-visited my code, and although I had set the mass matrix property, I passed the property as an argument without first using `odeset`; consequently, MATLAB ignored the option :). Nevertheless, I am not convinced that we can willy-nilly treat functions as variables without due justification; I can imagine conditions where in doing so we end up contradicting uniqueness of the solution via Picard-Lindeloff. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Ed, perhaps we should ask that as a separate question in order to get a definitive answer. Will you do the honours? I'd hate to unwittingly misrepresent your argument if I try to paraphrase it.

Comment: @RahulNarain Absolutely. I need to formulate some thoughts first, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking [Fabian's suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183292#comment422721_183300), we switch the dependent and independent variables, giving
$$\frac{CV}{t'(V)} = P + \frac{R_CC^2}{t'(V)^2}$$
because $V'(t) = \mathrm dV/\mathrm dt = (\mathrm dt/\mathrm dV)^{-1} = 1/t'(V)$. Since $t'(V)$ better not ever be zero, this is equivalent to
$$CVt'(V)=Pt'(V)^2+R_CC^2,$$
which is a quadratic equation in $t'(V)$. Over [Ed Gorcenski's remonstrations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183292#comment422890_183292), we hit this with the quadratic-formula hammer, yielding
$$t'(V) = \frac{CV}{2P} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{CV}{2P}\right)^2-\frac{R_CC^2}P}.$$
This can now be integrated as usual, using the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_irrational_functions#Integrals_involving_2) that
$$\int\sqrt{x^2-a^2}\,\mathrm dx = \frac12\left(x\sqrt{x^2-a^2} - a^2\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2-a^2})\right).$$
I haven't worked through by hand it myself, but Mathematica tells me that the integral simplifies to
$$t(V) = \frac{CV^2}{4P} \pm \frac{CV}{4P}\sqrt{V^2-4PR_C} \mp CR_C\log\big(V+\sqrt{V^2-4PR_C}\big) + \text{const},$$
which looks to be the same as [what Robert Israel got](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/183339/856).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely non-linear. Mathematica solves it, whereas WolframAlpha is not able to produce a formula. Here is the output of Mathematica 8.1, where I solved the equation $V(t)V'(t)=1+V'(t)^2$:

`{{v[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     1/8 (4 + 8 ArcSinh[Sqrt[-2 + #1]/2] - #1^2 - 
         Sqrt[-2 + #1] #1 Sqrt[2 + #1]) &][-(t/2) + C[1]]}, {v[t] -> 
   InverseFunction[
     1/8 (-4 + 8 ArcSinh[Sqrt[-2 + #1]/2] + #1^2 - 
         Sqrt[-2 + #1] #1 Sqrt[2 + #1]) &][t/2 + C[1]]}}`

Comment: The solution suggests that one should switch the dependent and independent variable and find an equation for $t(V)$ which then hopefully is separable.

Comment: Yes, but I posted my answer at 7pm and I was going to dinner, so I had no time to try :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maple 16's solution (switching to lowercase because I has a special meaning in Maple):

```
e1:= i(t) = c*diff(v(t),t);
e2:= v(t)*i(t)=p+r[c]*i(t)^2;
simplify(dsolve({e1,e2}));
```

$$\displaystyle [ \left\{ v \left( t \right) =r_{{c}}p \left( {\it LambertW} \left( -4\,r_{{c}}p{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-2\,t+r_{{c}}c+2\,{\it \_C1}}{r_{{c}}c}}}} \right) -1\\
\mbox{} \right)  \left(  \sqrt{-r_{{c}}p \left( {\it LambertW} \left( -4\,r_{{c}}p{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-2\,t+r_{{c}}c+2\,{\it \_C1}}{r_{{c}}c}}}}\\
\mbox{} \right)  \right) ^{-1}} \right) ^{-1} \left( {\it LambertW} \left( -4\,r_{{c}}p{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-2\,t+r_{{c}}c+2\,{\it \_C1}}{r_{{c}}c}}}} \right)  \right) ^{-1},v \left( t \right) =-r_{{c}}p \left( -1+{\it LambertW} \left( -1/4\,{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-2\,t+r_{{c}}c+2\,{\it \_C1}}{r_{{c}}c}}}}{r_{{c}}}^{-1}{p}^{-1} \right)  \right)  \sqrt{-{r_{{c}}}^{-1}{p}^{-1} \left( {\it LambertW} \left( -1/4\,{{\rm e}^{{\frac {-2\,t+r_{{c}}c+2\,{\it \_C1}}{r_{{c}}c}}}}{r_{{c}}}^{-1}{p}^{-1} \right)  \right) ^{-1}}\\
\mbox{} \right\} , \left\{ i \left( t \right) =c{\frac {d}{dt}}v \left( t \right)  \right\} ]
$$

It may actually be better to use the implicit form:

```
dsolve({e1,e2},implicit);
```

$$\displaystyle [ \left\{ t-1/4\,{\frac {c \left( v \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}}{p}}-1/4\,{\frac {cv \left( t \right)  \sqrt{ \left( v \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}-4\,r_{{c}}p}}{p}}+r_{{c}}c\ln  \left( v \left( t \right) + \sqrt{ \left( v \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}-4\,r_{{c}}p} \right) \\
\mbox{}-{\it \_C1}=0,t-1/4\,{\frac {c \left( v \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}}{p}}+1/4\,{\frac {cv \left( t \right)  \sqrt{ \left( v \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}-4\,r_{{c}}p}}{p}}-r_{{c}}c\ln  \left( v \left( t \right) + \sqrt{ \left( v \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}-4\,r_{{c}}p} \right) \\
\mbox{}-{\it \_C1}=0 \right\} , \left\{ i \left( t \right) =c{\frac {d}{dt}}v \left( t \right)  \right\} ]$$